# Python Tkinter Wait Until A List Is A Certain Length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

I'm trying to make a sequence memory program using Buttons in Tkinter. The problem is that I don't know how to make Tkinter wait until the 'entered_seq' list is 'ins_seq_num' long after showing the sequence. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, NORMAL, HIDDEN, Button, RIGHT, Frame
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time
from multiprocessing import Process

root = Tk()
root.title('Sequence Memory')
root.geometry('500x500')

button = {}
btn = []
ins_seq = []
ins_seq_num = 0
entered_seq = []

frame = Frame(root)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

c_seq = 0

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        c_seq+=1
        btn.append(Button(frame, text=c_seq, command= lambda: entered_seq.append(c_seq)))
        button.update({c_seq:(x,y)})
        btn[c_seq-1].grid(column=y, row=x, sticky="news")

frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(3)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(3)), weight=1)

wait_btn = Button(root)

submit = False

while True:
    entered_seq = []
    ins_seq_num += 1
    ins_seq.append(randint(1, 9))
    for but in ins_seq:
        btn[but-1].grid_forget()
        root.update()
        root.after(1000,btn[but-1].grid(column=button[but][1], row=button[but][0], sticky="news"))
        root.update()
    wait_btn.wait_variable(entered_seq)
```

I tried to use the wait_variable to wait until the list changes, but it doesn't do anything. Sometimes it opens a different window I do not want.

Comment: Using a while loop and tkinter is generally a recipe for disaster. Create your GUI with the buttons. Each button will use a lambda function to call a function with the row/column of the button clicked as arguments. The first time a button is pressed starts the game. Your code will then use the .after method to display the pattern to the user one at a time. Then your code will expect the user to press N buttons and have them match the random sequence. Your function will have a if-else structure in it to determine whether the game is in finished/show sequence/user play mode

Comment: Without re-writing your entire code, this is the best explanation I can give. Avoid while loops and the update method where every possible. Use the root.mainloop() method so that tkinter controls when to update the gui.

Comment: You should remove that incorrect ```while``` loop and call ```root.mainloop()```. Run a periodic tasks using the ```after()``` recursively.

Comment: How do you think I should change my code? I'm a bit new to tkinter, because I usually code using the CLI.